# Reactive services and scalability without Akka

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future, reactive-programming

I've read Reactive Manifesto for a couple of times and tried to wrap my head around all this reactive, async, non-blocking stuff. It's clear how to make scalable systems on top of Actors, but will i get the same effect, in term of scalability, asynchronous execution execution if i would actively use scala `Future` all over my code, every method would either accept or return a Future. Would such service be scalable and responsive?. Lets say that in this question i'm not much interested in event-driven and resilient part of the service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer reflects my experience using Akka in Scala and its `Actor` and `Future` types. I don't consider myself an expert, yet, but I've done a few systems using these libraries and feel I am beginning to develop a sense for how to use them.

The choice of using an Actor vs. a Future is about the nature of the concurrency you require. Futures compose monadically and in DAG-structured graphs, making certain computational structures very elegantly composed. But they have severe limitations. Basically, the computation that is performed concurrently within a Future must be self-contained (or at most reference only immutable external state) or you have not solved the problem of inter-thread interference with all the attendant risks such as deadlock, race conditions, unpredictable behavior or data structure corruption.

When your computation involves long-lived, mutable state, an Actor encapsulates that securely preventing corruption and race conditions. On the other hand, actors are not composable, but they do provide a lot of flexibility in how you construct networks of interacting computations. This is true only providing you don't limit actor responses to always and only sending them (the response to a request) back to the actor from which the request was received. If you only send responses to the requesting actor, you're limited to a tree-structured pattern of inter-actor interaction.

In any real, non-trivial system, you're very likely to use both formalisms, Future and Actor.